# How to detect encoding errors in a Node.js Buffer

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, buffer, node.js-stream

I'm reading a file in Node.js, into a `Buffer` object, and I'm decoding the UTF-8 content of the `Buffer` using `Buffer.toString('utf8')`. If there are encoding errors, I want to report a failure.

The `toString()` method handles decoding errors by substituting an `xFFFD` character, which I can detect by searching the result. But `xFFFD` is a legal character in the input file, and I don't want to report an error if the `xFFFD` was present and correctly encoded in the input.

Is there any way I can distinguish a `Buffer` that contains a legitimately-encoded `xFFFD` character from one that contains an encoding error?

Comment: I have found a workaround by doing `contents = buffer.toString('utf8'); if (contents.indexOf("\ufffd") >= 0 && !buffer.includes("\ufffd")) {...}` but it's very ugly and inefficient, and it doesn't handle the edge case where the input contains BOTH an FFFD character AND an encoding error.

Comment: One possibility could be using https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_class_util_textdecoder with the `fatal` option set to true.

Comment: @eol Thanks for the pointer, that looks promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution proposed by @eol in a comment on the question appears to meet the requirements.